# NavBar doesn't collapse in admin-Folder from ASP-Page

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

i have a Bootstrap-Navbar on a ASP-Page. The Navbar ist included in a MasterPage and working fine with all the sites in root-Directory.

Some Pages with Login-Functionality are in an admin-Folder. These Pages use the same MasterPage, but when beeing on such a page, the Navbar isn't collapsing when clicking on a MainMenu-Item. The only thing that happens, is in the adress-box in the browser is a "#" appearing at the end.

Can someone help me solving this Problem ?

Greetings
Gregor

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" style="background-color:#286090;width:100%;z-index:10;">
                <div class="container">
                    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar" style="background-color:white;width:50px;height:5px;padding:4px;margin:5px;"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar" style="background-color:white;width:50px;height:5px;padding:4px;margin:5px;"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar" style="background-color:white;width:50px;height:5px;padding:4px;margin:5px;"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><a href="../default.aspx" style="color:white;font-size:5em;margin-left:30px;"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="color:white;font-size:3em;margin-left:30px;padding-top:50px;">Serien</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level">
                                    <li><a href="../tagebuch.aspx" style="color:white;background-color:#286090;font-size:3em;">Serien-Diary</a></li>                                                           
                                    <li><a href="../tagebuch.aspx?unbeendete=ja" style="color:white;background-color:#286090;font-size:3em;">Nicht-Beendete</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="../tagebuch.aspx?todo=ja" style="color:white;background-color:#286090;font-size:3em;">Warteliste</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="../admin/sichtungTV.aspx" style="color:white;background-color:#286090;font-size:3em;">Serien-Sichtung anlegen</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="../admin/logoUpload.aspx" style="color:white;background-color:#286090;font-size:3em;">Serien-Logo hochladen</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="../neueste.aspx?serien=true" style="color:white;background-color:#286090;font-size:3em;">DB Chronologie</a></li>                                    
                                    <li><a href="../neueste.aspx?chrono=true" style="color:white;background-color:#286090;font-size:3em;">Sichtungs-Chrono</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="../admin/serienDaten.aspx" style="color:white;background-color:#286090;font-size:3em;">Serien-Daten</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="../empfehlungen.aspx?serien=true" style="color:white;background-color:#286090;font-size:3em;">Empfehlungen</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="color:white;font-size:3em;margin-left:30px;padding-top:50px;">Filme</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level">
                                    <li><a href="../letzteFilmsichtungen.aspx" style="color:white;background-color:#286090;font-size:3em;">Film-Diary</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="../admin/eintragen.aspx" style="color:white;background-color:#286090;font-size:3em;">in DB anlegen</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="../neueste.aspx" style="color:white;background-color:#286090;font-size:3em;">DB Chronologie</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="../admin/sichtungFilm.aspx" style="color:white;background-color:#286090;font-size:3em;">Film-Sichtung anlegen</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="../empfehlungen.aspx" style="color:white;background-color:#286090;font-size:3em;">Empfehlungen</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://filmliste.de" style="color:white;background-color:#286090;font-size:3em;">Liste Filtern</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="../empfehlungen.aspx?quelle=dvd" style="color:white;background-color:#286090;font-size:3em;">DVD's</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="../empfehlungen.aspx?quelle=bluray" style="color:white;background-color:#286090;font-size:3em;">BluRay's</a></li>
                                    <li>
                                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="color:white;background-color:#286090;font-size:3em;">FILTERN<b class="caret"></b></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="color:white;background-color:#286090;font-size:3em;">FSK</a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <li><a href="../empfehlungen.aspx?filter=beschlagnahmt" style="color:white;background-color:#286090;font-size:3em;">Beschlagnahmen</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="../empfehlungen.aspx?filter=spio" style="color:white;background-color:#286090;font-size:3em;">SPIO/JK</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="../empfehlungen.aspx?filter=aliste" style="color:white;background-color:#286090;font-size:3em;">Liste A</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="../empfehlungen.aspx?filter=bliste" style="color:white;background-color:#286090;font-size:3em;">Liste B</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="color:white;background-color:#286090;font-size:3em;">Genre</a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <li><a href="../empfehlungen.aspx?genre=splatter" style="color:white;background-color:#286090;font-size:3em;">Splatter</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="../empfehlungen.aspx?genre=horror" style="color:white;background-color:#286090;font-size:3em;">Horror</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="../empfehlungen.aspx?genre=action" style="color:white;background-color:#286090;font-size:3em;">Action</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="../empfehlungen.aspx?genre=scifi" style="color:white;background-color:#286090;font-size:3em;">Science-Fiction</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="../empfehlungen.aspx?genre=fantasy" style="color:white;background-color:#286090;font-size:3em;">Fantasy</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="color:white;font-size:3em;margin-left:30px;padding-top:50px;">Sonstiges</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level">
                                    <li><a href="../admin/einstellungen.aspx" style="color:white;background-color:#286090;font-size:3em;">Einstellungen</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="../protokoll.aspx" style="color:white;background-color:#286090;font-size:3em;">Protokoll</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="../default.aspx" style="color:white;background-color:#286090;font-size:3em;">HOME</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#oben" style="color:white;font-size:5em;margin-left:50px;"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-up"></i></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.container -->
            </nav>
```

Comment: Without code we can't do anything

Comment: Here is the HTML of the Navbar. Need something more?